# neocomplete autocompletion not working correctly with syntax files

Tags: angularjs, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting, omnicomplete, neocomplete

This section is in my .vimrc:

```
" Enable omni completion
autocmd FileType css setlocal omnifunc=csscomplete#CompleteCSS
autocmd FileType html,markdown setlocal omnifunc=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
autocmd FileType python setlocal omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
autocmd FileType xml setlocal omnifunc=xmlcomplete#CompleteTags
```

When editing .html files, i hit `<` and the neocomplete CompleteTags suggestion list pops up as expected.

Afterwards, when entering `< div ng-` (as in angularjs directives [no space]) nothing pops up, despite of having the syntax files for angularjs installed (through the javascript-libraries-syntax.vim plugin)

However, when executing the line 
`set ofu=syntaxcomplete#Complete` or similarily `set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete` everything works and i see the list of directives.

1. shouldn't neocomplete use syntax keywords out of the box?
2. can I use multiple omnifuncs to resolve this issue? both #CompleteTags and #Complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. shouldn't neocomplete use syntax keywords out of the box?

It does (from neocomplete documentation, [neocomplete-syntax](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim/blob/4bf7526a1c8cca9f8614e8a09178f334eaca0481/doc/neocomplete.txt#L181-L185) section ):

```
 If you want to complete the candidates from syntax files, you need to
 install the neco-syntax plugin (https://github.com/Shougo/neco-syntax).
```

> 2. can I use multiple omnifuncs to resolve this issue? both #CompleteTags and #Complete?

Of course you can (again from neocomplete documentation, [g:neocomplete#sources#omni#functions](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim/blob/4bf7526a1c8cca9f8614e8a09178f334eaca0481/doc/neocomplete.txt#L640-L649) section):

```
g:neocomplete#sources#omni#functions
        This dictionary which appoints omni source call functions.
        The key is 'filetype'.  The value is omnifunc name String or
        List of omnifunc name String.
        If |g:neocomplete#sources#omni#functions| [&filetype] is
        undefined, omni source calls 'omnifunc'.
        If the key is "_", used for all filetypes.

        Default value is {}.
```

So add the following *dictionary* to your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:neocomplete#sources#omni#functions = {
  \ 'html': ['htmlcomplete#CompleteTags', 'syntaxcomplete#Complete']
  \ }
```

Both of first or second approach should resolve the issue.

Comment: I pressed 'add comment' too early by accident and can't seem to find an edit button up here.

The first method (the neocomplete syntax plugin) did nothing for me. I removed it and then tried the second approach (omni functions dictionary) that did the job.

However, i still have a semi related issue. my 'vim-javascript' plugin seem to collide with something (i'd bet on the libraries plugin) and mess up my syntax files. syntax highlighting for 'ng-repeat' (i.e) doesn't work, although autocompletion does.

Removing 'vim-javascript' solves that, but I don't wanna give up on that plugin.

Comment: @user2263786, I have got no idea. please consider a new question for this issue. maybe someone else out there also had experienced same collision.